# How to set a negative Sentinal Value?

Tags: java, sentinel

I'm in a College Java class and we've just gotten to Methods. However, I appear to be having some issues with setting a Sentinel Value. I have one set up correctly, apparently, already and that is set to 0. But now I've gotta set one up for any and all negative values, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //States and initializes multiple variables.
    int id;

    //Creates the scanner class.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Introduces the USER as to what they are inputing.
    System.out.println("Hello. Welcome to our webpage. Please enter your ID"
            + " before continuing."
            + " Valid IDs are between 10000 and 40000.");
    System.out.println();

    do {
        System.out.print("ID: ");
        id = keyboard.nextInt();
        if ((id < 10000 || id > 40000)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input detected. Please try again.");
        }
    } while ((id < 10000 || id > 40000));
    System.out.println();

    calcSubtotal();
}

public static double calcSubtotal() {

    double testPrice = -1, itemPrice = 0;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (testPrice != 0) {

        //Takes user input, while also addressing it a count.
        System.out.print("Enter item price or zero or a negative value"
                + " to quit => ");
        testPrice = input.nextDouble();
        if (testPrice != 0) {
            itemPrice += testPrice;
            count++;
        } else if (testPrice < -1) {
            itemPrice += testPrice;
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Count test: " + count);

    return itemPrice;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You say `"enter a negative value to quit"` inside your `calcSubtotal` method but you never actually quit the loop when a negative value is entered. Try to implement a similar approach to this:

```
if (value < 0) { 
   //Do some stuff once you detect the negative sentinel value
   //Then break out of the loop which will exit THE ENTIRE LOOP immediately
   //after the current value being evaluated is negative
   break;
{
```

Also wanted to point out that you never handle testPrice being equal to -1, you should use <= -1 or < 0 so all negative cases are handled.